# SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ , for var names[] array

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with input array, attempting a Javascript challenge on CodeWars.

Here is the instruction: Implement a function likes :: [String] -> String, which must take in input array, containing the names of people who like an item. It must return the display text as shown in the examples:

```
likes [] // must be "no one likes this"
likes ["Peter"] // must be "Peter likes this"
likes ["Jacob", "Alex"] // must be "Jacob and Alex like this"
likes ["Max", "John", "Mark"] // must be "Max, John and Mark like this"
likes ["Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"] // must be "Alex, Jacob and 2 others like this"
```

Basicliy its like the facebook like system. Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Here is my trial code

```
function likes (names) {
    var names[7];
    if ( names.length=0) {
        return "nobody likes this"
    } else if (names.length=1) {
        return names[0]+"likes this";
    } else if (names.length=2) {
        return names[0]+names[1]"like this"
    } else if (names.length=3) {
        return names[0]+''+names [1]+''+names[2]+''+ " likes this"
    } else (names.length >3) {
        return  names[0]+''+names [1]+''+ names.length-1 + "likes this"
    }
}
```

Comment: Function call should be `likes()` not `likes[]`

Answer (score 0):

`var names` is the syntax to declare a variable called `names`.

`names[7]` is the syntax to read the value of `names` and then access a property on the resulting object named `7`.

You can't create a variable and access a property on its value at the same time … the value of the variable hasn't been assigned yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your code, Simple concept

```
var likes=[];

//call this like function with name as parameter, while click the like button
function like(name)
{
 likes.push(name);
}

 function viewlikes(){// here you need write the condition and call where you want display the details         
   if(likes.length==0)
     {
     return " nobody likes this"
     }

 if(likes.length==1)
     {
     return likes[0] + " like this" 
     }

 if(likes.length==2)
     {
     return likes[0] + "," + likes[1] + " like this"    
     }
 if(likes.length==3)
     {
     return likes[0] + "," + likes[1] + " and " + likes[2] + " like this"    
     }
     return likes[0] + "," + likes[1] + " and " + likes.length-2 " others like this"
    }
```